# Udemy API 2.0 with PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm struggling to get working the Udemy API with authentication.

What I have, in a plain PHP file:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $url = "https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/238934?fields[course]=url,title,primary_subcategory,primary_category,price,image_480x270,headline,description";
    //  Initiate curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // Execute
    $c_id = base64_encode('my id');
    $c_sid = base64_encode('my secret');

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Udemy-Client-Id: '.$c_id.'','X-Udemy-Client-Secret: '.$c_sid.'',"Authorization: base64 encoded value of client-id:client-secret","Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
    echo curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    // Close
    curl_close($ch);


    $result = json_decode($result);
    echo $result;


?>
```

Despite all my efforts, I always keep getting a 403 error without any other information.
I copied/paste my Udemy API data from website.

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

i read this

```
Authorization: base64 encoded value of client-id:client-secret
```

you just encode client id & client secret to base64
*base64 of client id:base64 of client secret*
and don't forget to add ***Basic*** after ***Authorization:*** 
source https://www.udemy.com/developers/affiliate/

i don't know for what X-Udemy-Client-Id & X-Udemy-Client-Secret
but if you want use that, you can try this at your httpheader

```
$headers = array(
    'X-Udemy-Client-Id: '.$c_id.'',
    'X-Udemy-Client-Secret: '.$c_sid.'',
    'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($c_id.':'.$c_sid).'',
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: I already encoded per your suggestions. If you check my main code I base64_encode both ID's . But I've tried your code and keep getting the same result. Thanks.